# Python - TicTacToe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pypi, tic-tac-toe

In this question I have to create a TicTacToe game in python which will run in terminal. This is a 2player game and if any player wins by the rules of TicTacToe, Winner =  player 1/2 has to be printed.

I'm getting a winner statement when I have three 0's or 1's diagonally but I'm not getting winner in other two cases (horizontally and vertically)

Please help find the error in my code

```
import numpy as np

def create_board():
    return (np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0]]))


def coordinates(board, player):
    i, j, cn = (-1, -1, 0)
    while (i > 3 or i < 0 or j < 0 or j > 3) or (board[i][j] != 0):
        if cn > 0:
            print("Wrong Input! Try Again")
        print("Player {}'s turn".format(player))
        i = int(input("x-coordinates: "))
        j = int(input("y-coordinates: "))
        i = i - 1
        j = j - 1
        cn = cn + 1
    board[i][j] = player
    return board


def row_win(board, player):
    for x in range(len(board)):
        win = True

        for y in range(len(board)):
            if board[x, y] != player:
                win = False
                continue
    return win


def col_win(board, player):
    for x in range(len(board)):
        win = True

        for y in range(len(board)):
            if board[y][x] != player:
                win = False
                continue

    return win


def diag_win(board, player):
    win = True
    y = 0
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if board[x][x] != player:
            win = False
    if win:
        return win
    win = True
    if win:
        for x in range(len(board)):
            y = len(board) - 1 - x
            if board[x][y] != player:
                win = False
    return win


def evaluate(board):
    winner = 0

    for player in [1, 2]:
        if (row_win(board, player) or
                col_win(board, player) or
                diag_win(board, player)):
            winner = player

    if np.all(board != 0) and winner == 0:
        winner = -1
    return winner


def play_game():
    board, winner, counter = create_board(), 0, 1
    print(board)
    while winner == 0:
        for player in [1, 2]:
            board = coordinates(board, player)
            print("Board after " + str(counter) + " move")
            print(board)
            counter += 1
            winner = evaluate(board)
            if winner != 0:
                break
    return winner

print("Winner is: " + str(play_game()))
```

Comment: `continue` should be `break`.

Comment: `numpy` is a pretty heavy dependency for something as simple as a 3x3 array. The only  NumPy-specific feature you are using is `np.all`, which you can replace with `all(x != 0 for row in board for x in row)` when `board` is an ordinary nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this is the board:

```
x x x 
o o x
x o o
```

Your `row_win` checks then first row, `win` remains `True`.
It then proceeds to check the second row, `win` is set to `False`. After the last row the function ends up reporting that the player has not won, even though it has.

To fix this change your `row_win` and `col_win` to something like this:

```
def row_win(board, player):
    for row in board:
        if all(cell == player for cell in row):
            return True
    return False
```

If all the cells of a row are equal to the player, then the player has won.
If none of the rows have all cells equal to the player, then the player has not won.